# Every n rows down select the next row from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A list of names (Sheet "Name") which need to put on the following sheet in 5 (preferably variable number) row gaps.

```
A3 = Name!A1
A9 = Name!A2
A15 = Name!A3
A21 = Name!A4
```

I've tried using the ROW() in conjunction with IF/THEN/ELSE condition loop,checking for blank row, which fell short.  More googling has lead me to the the offset() operand but that's accessing cells rather than writing in them.

I'm quite happy to use VBA active cell but the VB editor doesn't work properly on this machine so for the time being i'm trying to solve this task using EXCEL.

Answer (score 1):

Ooption A:

Put this formula into A3,

```
=INDEX(Name!A:A, INT(ROW()/6)+1)
```

Copy to A9, A15 and A21.

Option B:

Put this formula into A3,

```
=IF(NOT(MOD(ROW()-3, 6)), INDEX(Name!A:A, INT(ROW()/6)+1), "")
```

Fill down to A21.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can offset based on the number of rows you've already filled. 
=OFFSET(Name!$A$1,counta(A$1:A2),0)

This will work as long as there is no content within other rows between A3,A9,A15,A21.

A little more dynamic would be to add a reference row in the Name tab that would allow you to do a VLOOKUP/MATCH/etc within the new tab. That is very handy when you want to make a variable number of rows in the new tab for each row in the other tab (for example, table 1 lists a quantity and you need a row for each quantity in the next tab--the lookup reference would be a cumulative sum of all of the quantities and you could lookup to that reference).